# embed any web page

Tags: html, iframe, embed

i would like to embed the public view of my Google Scholar page into my personal webpage. I used the iframe tags, however the resulting box is just empty. What are the general rule where iframe tag applies?

Comment: can you put some code

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: you cannot, because google refuses to allow other sites to embed its pages. Actually, if you are using a debugger, it should warn you that Google is using the same origin policy on its response:
Refused to display 'http://scholar.google.fr/...' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Answer (score 0):

Want to know all about ? Follow the link below.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

My opinion is to avoid iframes because of bookmarking and navigation.
Here are some alternatives
[Alternatives to Iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574214/alternatives-to-iframe)
http://icant.co.uk/articles/crossdomain-ajax-with-jquery/index.html

Comment: If you're going to link to a resource to find out more about certain HTML elements you should link to the [W3 HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-iframe-element). W3Schools is generally frowned upon.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this is by exporting all my publications from Google Scholar to a bib file then use bibbase.org to create a publications page using the generated bib file. You can embed the generated page into your website. Works fine and looks good.